# MsBuild DefineConstants from .pubxml doesnt work correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild, csproj

I have ASP.NET Core + Blazor app (default template) with 2 projects.

When I create an IIS publish profile:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>04df5cd2-b320-4d8c-85bd-d25cd9b83925</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>https://mytestserver.com:8172/msdeploy.axd</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>TestApp</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>true</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>true</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <EnableMsDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMsDeployAppOffline>
    <_TargetId>IISWebDeploy</_TargetId>

    <DefineConstants>ModuleOneTest</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

So `<DefineConstants>ModuleOneTest</DefineConstants>` affects only code in Server project (which contain publish profile) and code:

```
public string GetConstants()
{
    List<string> constants = new List<string>();
#if ModuleOneTest
    constants.Add("ModuleOneTest From Server");
#endif

    return string.Join(", ", constants);
}
```

This works and add test string ("ModuleOneTest From Server") but in referenced project (client project added to server as a reference by default template) this is not working:

```
public string GetConstants()
{
    List<string> constants = new List<string>();
#if ModuleOneTest
    constants.Add("ModuleOneTest From Client");
#else
    constants.Add("Not defined");
#endif

    return string.Join(", ", constants);
}
```

and it returns "Not defined".

How can I fix this issue to work correctly with multiple projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add conditional symbol, modify the client project file as shown below:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ModuleOneTestEnabled)'=='true'">
  <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);ModuleOneTest</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Pass the property on server side publish profile for that you can use this command:

```
dotnet publish Serverapp.csproj /p:ModuleOneTestEnabled=true /p:PublishProfile=ProfileName
```

Comment: This work really good with console command. Spent whole day to configure .pubxml iis deploy profile to make same output but it make different output each time and sometimes depend on clearing bin and obj folders. Guess I will use console command for now. Thanks.